# Office 2016 can not print, all other app can. Windows 10 HP 1510

Tags: windows, hp, printing, microsoft-office

**Context**

Windows 10 Enterprise with very latest updates, Office 2016, HP Deskjet 1510 with the very latest drivers (wiped out old drivers, reinsalled all with the very latest versions)

**Symptoms**

- Printer test page: Works
- Generally all program can print
- Office applications, Excel, Word can not print: The printed doc shows up in the queue, then disappears with no error.
- After this happens once (trying to print from Office app), sometimes no application can print until I restart the machine.

**What I've tried so far**

- Restart spooler: No success, Office still can not print
- Wipe old HP driver dlls, by physically deleting the from everywhere, then installing the latest. Btw in the latest the dlls are the same as the currently used.

**Question**

There was a time, I clearly recall, when this printer was working in the Windows 10 installation with Office 2016. What went wrong, and how can I repair?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Office program is licensed? It happened to me once when my colleague's Office was not activated.

Comment: Yes, Office is fully licenced with MSDN subscription and activated. The machine is restored with Windows System images (using all built in Windows features), to the very same actual hardware. All Office functions are working otherwise

Comment: Manual deletion of driver DLL's is usually a bad idea because you delete the DLL but not the registry settings. If you want to uninstall a printer driver you should use the `Print Management` administrative tool, go to the drivers section and then right click in the driver that you want to remove.

Comment: I've uninstalled as it is written, **then** deleted the dlls. The error was present before I did anything driver and/or printer related

Comment: Can you print to the "Microsoft PDF Printer"? just to check if it's office or the printer that is acting up.

Comment: It seems it is Office. If I print to PDF printer, the file Save Print Output as dialog opents, I define the file name, but no actual file is created.